# Twilio returning resource not found for sms, after retrieving it from the api

Tags: twilio

I've reviewed every post I can find about resource not found on twilio.  There is nothing wrong with my credentials.  In fact, I use the api to retrieve the messages, then I get a not found error when trying to update the messages that the api just told me exist.  I've spent hours on this and it's driving me nuts. Below is my code.  The read function returns the sid, which I can look up in my twilio console, but then I'm told it doesn't exist when trying to update the message using that very same sid. The console gets a readout of the first message sid, then the error is thrown with the following:  Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException: 'The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages/SMc7943a93549acef10f1e49876a8652b6.json was not found'

```
    static readonly string accountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    static readonly string authToken = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var messages = MessageResource.Read(
            dateSent: new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0)
        );

            foreach(var message in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
                MessageResource.Update(pathSid: message.Sid, "");
            }

    }
```

Comment: So, using MessageResource.Fetch(pathSid: 'same sid as before') returns the message and I can access it's contents..... but the Update and Delete function of the api return the resource not found for the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows the AccountSid is missing from the path as there is a double slash:

> Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException: 'The requested resource
> /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages/SMc7943a93549acef10f1e49876a8652b6.json
> was not found'

The path should be something like:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{{ACCOUNTSID}}/Messages/SMc7943a93549acef10f1e49876a8652b6.json
```

The update you are trying to doesn't appear to be valid unless you are trying to [redact the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#update-a-message-resource):

```
MessageResource.Update(pathSid: message.Sid, "");
```

If you are trying to redact the message body:

```
MessageResource.Update(pathSid: message.Sid, body: "");
```

If you are trying to delete:

```
MessageResource.Delete(pathSid: "MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

If the delete/update still aren't working, try casting the ResourceSet of MessageResource to a list:

```
static readonly string accountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
static readonly string authToken = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var messages = MessageResource.Read(
    dateSent: new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0)
);

    var messageList = messages.ToList();    

    foreach(var message in messageList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
        MessageResource.Delete(pathSid: message.Sid);
    }

}
```

Comment: ok, so the Twilio documentation doesn't show the need to specify with is the pathSid and with is the body, but putting that in does correct the issue.  It was assuming the "" I had for the body was the pathSid, which was causing the double slashes.  Wow.... it's always the stupid things that take the most time to figure out.

Comment: I think the issue is that you specified pathSid but not the body parameters. It should work if you left off the pathSid: MessageResource.Update(sid, ""); Another reason to specify the parameter name :)

Comment: Actually, the new version of the app does not work leaving both off. Twilight verified this as an unintended bug this morning. It does work with both parameters specified.